# Git : Query with respect to cherrypick a commit in Git

Tags: git

I have two branches namely master and development .
I need to pick only some  certain commits from the development 
branch and merge them to the master .

I tried to use `git cherry-pick` , but not sure if i am doing it right way

Do i need to cherry pick **a400452d64** OR **a7644fc2bc7b09fe88cb1cbb75e0547dd1d7321d**
**Please see the image**

[image]

i have followed the below approach .

```
git checkout master 

git pull
```

`git cherry-pick a400452d64`

OR

```
git cherry-pick  a7644fc2bc7b09fe88cb1cbb75e0547dd1d7321d

git commit -m "My Commit"  # Is this necessary ??

git push -u origin master   # Is this necessary ??
```

Please  let me know if i am doing anything wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Parent" commit is the one before that commit, so the 'commit' hash is the one you want to use. For the avoidance of doubt you can do:

```
git show a7644fc2bc7b09fe88cb1cbb75e0547dd1d7321d
```

and check it's the right commit before you do it:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git cherry-pick a7644fc2bc7b09fe88cb1cbb75e0547dd1d7321d
git push
```

Specifying the origin on the push is probably not necessary if the upstream is configured correctly.